# InfiniBand RDMA latency test on Xen's dom0 crashes

Tags: xen, infiniband, mellanox

The short story: while setting up InfiniBand connection between two servers, I cannot complete the RDMA latency test. It crashes even with breaking the ssh connection.

The long story. The first server is the Xen 4.4 with Ubuntu 14.04 as dom0 (hostname is xen). The second server is a usual server with Ubuntu 14.04 (hostname is node3). They both have Mellanox MT25208 HCAs connected over IB switch. Both have all the kernel modules loaded, OpenSM installed. The IPoIB works fine. The bare `ibping` goes both directions xen -> node3 and node3 -> xen. The problem occurs when I try `ib_rdma_lat` test. Here are the steps that lead to `ib_rdma_lat` and next `sshd` crash on xen.

1. On the xen I run `ib_rdma_lat`.
2. On the node3 I run `ib_rdma_lat xen`
3. The ssh connection to xen closes.
4. This is the output before ssh's connection close.

`root@xen:~/tmp/22# ib_rdma_lat
local address: LID 0x03 QPN 0x10406 PSN 0x9f903b RKey 0x40004000 VAddr 0x000000017e4001
remote address: LID 0x01 QPN 0x10406 PSN 0xd8c16e RKey 0x20004000 VAddr 0x000000013fd001
Connection to xen closed by remote host. Connection to xen closed.`

I googled, and the only thing that I could do was tunig the `ib_mthca`'s module parameters `num_mtt` and `log_mtts_per_seg`. As it is said in the article http://community.mellanox.com/docs/DOC-1120. I set them on both servers as `num_mtt=4194304` and `log_mtts_per_seg=4`. I did this while experimenting with those values so that the `ib_mthca` module would load correct.
But this didn't help. `ib_rdma_lat` still crashes on xen. Here's the log:

```
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170180] ib_rdma_lat invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170189] ib_rdma_lat cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170195] CPU: 0 PID: 2889 Comm: ib_rdma_lat Tainted: G    B   W    3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170198] Hardware name: Supermicro X9DRFF-iG+/-7G+/-iTG+/-7TG+/X9DRFF-iG+/-7G+/-iTG+/-7TG+, BIOS 3.0 07/29/2013
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170202]  0000000000000000 ffff880f175ebc68 ffffffff8171bcb4 ffff880f1ae02fe0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170209]  ffff880f175ebcf0 ffffffff817165ef ffff880f1a96afe0 0000000000000000
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170213]  00000000016ad5c1 ffff880f1a96afe0 ffffffff817246aa ffffffff8172417b
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170217] Call Trace:
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170236]  [<ffffffff8171bcb4>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170242]  [<ffffffff817165ef>] dump_header+0x7f/0x1f1
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170248]  [<ffffffff817246aa>] ? error_exit+0x2a/0x60
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170253]  [<ffffffff8172417b>] ? retint_restore_args+0x5/0x6
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170260]  [<ffffffff81151bfe>] oom_kill_process+0x1ce/0x330
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170269]  [<ffffffff812d3ac5>] ? security_capable_noaudit+0x15/0x20
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170273]  [<ffffffff81152334>] out_of_memory+0x414/0x450
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170278]  [<ffffffff811523df>] pagefault_out_of_memory+0x6f/0x80
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170284]  [<ffffffff81714c38>] mm_fault_error+0x8e/0x180
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170289]  [<ffffffff81727f01>] __do_page_fault+0x4a1/0x560
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170299]  [<ffffffff81111116>] ? __acct_update_integrals+0x76/0xe0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170305]  [<ffffffff8111155c>] ? acct_account_cputime+0x1c/0x20
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170312]  [<ffffffff8109d7db>] ? account_user_time+0x8b/0xa0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170316]  [<ffffffff8109ddf4>] ? vtime_account_user+0x54/0x60
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170320]  [<ffffffff81727fda>] do_page_fault+0x1a/0x70
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170324]  [<ffffffff81724448>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170326] Mem-Info:
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170329] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170334] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170336] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170339] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 135
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170341] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170344] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 124
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170351] active_anon:7920 inactive_anon:23 isolated_anon:0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170351]  active_file:20177 inactive_file:37521 isolated_file:0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170351]  unevictable:8 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170351]  free:15211440 slab_reclaimable:4583 slab_unreclaimable:8427
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170351]  mapped:4644 shmem:408 pagetables:993 bounce:0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170351]  free_cma:0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170358] Node 0 DMA free:15888kB min:8kB low:8kB high:12kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15972kB managed:15888kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170367] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1980 60135 60135
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170372] Node 0 DMA32 free:2017364kB min:1032kB low:1288kB high:1548kB active_anon:992kB inactive_anon:4kB active_file:2596kB inactive_file:5756kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:2045472kB managed:2031128kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:692kB shmem:32kB slab_reclaimable:428kB slab_unreclaimable:472kB kernel_stack:40kB pagetables:132kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170381] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 58154 58154
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170386] Node 0 Normal free:58812508kB min:30348kB low:37932kB high:45520kB active_anon:30688kB inactive_anon:88kB active_file:78112kB inactive_file:144328kB unevictable:32kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:60853112kB managed:59550432kB mlocked:32kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:17884kB shmem:1600kB slab_reclaimable:17904kB slab_unreclaimable:33236kB kernel_stack:1704kB pagetables:3840kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170394] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170398] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB (U) 0*32kB 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (R) 3*4096kB (M) = 15888kB
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170416] Node 0 DMA32: 1*4kB (M) 12*8kB (UEM) 7*16kB (UE) 2*32kB (UM) 1*64kB (U) 2*128kB (UM) 0*256kB 1*512kB (E) 1*1024kB (E) 2*2048kB (ER) 491*4096kB (M) = 2017364kB
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170434] Node 0 Normal: 67*4kB (UM) 34*8kB (UEM) 16*16kB (UEM) 38*32kB (UM) 26*64kB (UM) 22*128kB (UEM) 15*256kB (UEM) 2*512kB (M) 1*1024kB (M) 3*2048kB (UEM) 14354*4096kB (MR) = 58812508kB
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170468] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170470] 58105 total pagecache pages
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170473] 0 pages in swap cache
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170476] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/189
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170478] Free swap  = 33517564kB
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170480] Total swap = 33517564kB
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170482] 15728639 pages RAM
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170483] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170485] 325670 pages reserved
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170487] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170496] [  375]     0   375     4935      228      14        0             0 upstart-udev-br
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170501] [  384]     0   384    12927      485      28        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170505] [  571]   102   571     9887      391      23        0             0 dbus-daemon
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170509] [  590]   101   590    63961      318      27        0             0 rsyslogd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170513] [  596]     0   596     4823      373      14        0             0 bluetoothd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170516] [  606]     0   606    18680      893      40        0             0 cupsd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170520] [  614]     0   614     5870      106      16        0             0 rpc.idmapd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170523] [  622]     0   622    10863      454      26        0             0 systemd-logind
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170528] [  702]     0   702     3984      308      13        0             0 upstart-file-br
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170531] [  877]     0   877     5855      275      18        0             0 rpcbind
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170534] [  898]   111   898     5386      347      15        0             0 rpc.statd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170538] [  901]     0   901     3848      184      13        0             0 upstart-socket-
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170541] [ 1300]   105  1300     7861      513      21        0             0 ntpd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170545] [ 1374]     0  1374     5268      237      13        0             0 getty
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170548] [ 1378]     0  1378     5268      235      13        0             0 getty
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170551] [ 1384]     0  1384     5268      237      13        0             0 getty
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170555] [ 1385]     0  1385     5268      238      13        0             0 getty
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170558] [ 1388]     0  1388     5268      238      13        0             0 getty
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170561] [ 1427]     0  1427    15341      762      33        0         -1000 sshd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170564] [ 1443]     0  1443     5914      257      17        0             0 cron
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170568] [ 1554]     0  1554     2750      242      11        0             0 xenstored
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170571] [ 1566]     0  1566    22752      261      19        0             0 xenconsoled
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170575] [ 1613]     0  1613    73631     1045      48        0             0 polkitd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170578] [ 1885]   113  1885     7052      249      18        0             0 dnsmasq
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170581] [ 2004]     0  2004   148275      997      39        0             0 console-kit-dae
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170585] [ 2166]     0  2166    23985      237      21        0             0 xl
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170589] [ 2303]     0  2303     5268      237      13        0             0 getty
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170592] [ 2378]     0  2378    82712      784      23        0             0 opensm
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170595] [ 2379]     0  2379    65942      358      22        0             0 opensm
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170598] [ 2450]   106  2450    91259     1269      74        0             0 whoopsie
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170602] [ 2453]     0  2453    93762     3220     114        0             0 libvirtd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170605] [ 2634]     0  2634    26407     1058      54        0             0 sshd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170608] [ 2671]  1000  2671    26407      501      52        0             0 sshd
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170612] [ 2672]  1000  2672     7041     1040      17        0             0 bash
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170615] [ 2749]     0  2749    17566      547      36        0             0 sudo
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170618] [ 2750]     0  2750     7063     1074      16        0             0 bash
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170622] [ 2889]     0  2889     3732      213      12        0             0 ib_rdma_lat
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170625] Out of memory: Kill process 2453 (libvirtd) score 0 or sacrifice child
Aug  4 00:12:52 localhost kernel: [ 4011.170729] Killed process 2453 (libvirtd) total-vm:375048kB, anon-rss:4748kB, file-rss:8132kB
```

The xen (dom0) has 60GB of RAM. And the node3 has 180GB of RAM.
Here are some logs and command outputs that I made for diagnosing the problem.

1. `dmesg` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/dmesg.xen.log
2. `xl dmesg` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/xl-dmesg.xen.log
3. parameters of the loaded `ib_mthca` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/ib_mthca.xen.log
4. `ibhosts` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/ibhosts.xen.log
5. `ibstat` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/ibstat.xen.log
6. `ibstatus` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/ibstatus.xen.log
7. `lsmod | grep rdma` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/lsmod-rdma.xen.log
8. `lspci -s 04:00.0 -k` on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/lspci.xen.log
9. a cut from `/var/log/syslog` after `ib_rdma_lat` crash on xen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8057759/ib_mthca/syslog.xen

Can anyone advise me anything, please?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of observations:

1. You are running a *very old* device/driver (mthca) on a *relatively new OS* (Ubuntu 14.04). Unless somebody corrects me, I don't believe that anyone has really tested this.
   Where did you get the driver from? Which OFED version is it?
2. The test is killed by the oom-killer, which means that you have ran out of memory.
   That MTT stuff is related to being able to register/pin *more* memory - it's when you have more physical memory that you're able to pin with the default driver configuration. This is not the problem in your case.
   Please go back to the default settings.

Now, I'm guesstimating, but it might be that you have THP (transparrent huge pages) enabled on your machines, and the test doesn't really know how to handle them, which causes it to allocate large amount of pages as if they were usual pages.

Please [disable THP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/hugeadm.8.html) and try again.

Comment: The driver came from the distro. I didn't install it or build it from sources. I just inserted the HCA and saw that it appeared in the lspci. How to know for sure which OFED version do I have?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Please disable THP on both hosts and try again.

Comment: The package `hugepages` was not installed at all. When I installed it, rebooted and issued the `huegadm --thp-never` it gave me `hugeadm:ERROR: Couldn't open /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I really can't tell what is the problem here...

Infiniband/RDMA SW package is called "OFED".
Mellanox has it's own package called "Mellanox OFED".
First MLNX OFED version that officially supports Ubuntu 14.04 is MLNX_OFED 2.2-1.0.1.
Last version that had mthca is probably MLNX_OFED 1.5.3-4.0.42.
There are couple of years between these two versions...

[http://www.mellanox.com/page/mlnx_ofed_matrix?mtag=linux_sw_drivers]

Other than upgrading HCA, I suggest to try older distro.

Also, you might find technical help in the Linux RDMA mailing list
[http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.rdma]